# Send sar series to grafana

Tags: performance, monitoring, sar, sysstat

[`sar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) of `sysstat` package produces a lot of useful information about system usage regarding various resources;

My question (since after a brief query I was unable to find a useful suggestion / solution) is whether it is possible to send these statistics to a plotting tool, **preferably** `grafana`.

Comment: `sar` outputs to stdout, so its results can certainly be piped to another tool.  Could you be more specific about which statistic(s) you want to plot, and what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Grafana can visualize data from different databases.
So, you can try save data from `sar` to the database like InfluxDB or another time-series database.